# CSS, text goes 'inside' the div container and partially hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3, `.media` element

```html
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" style="max-width: 70px;" 
           @if($listing->Agent->picture != '')
            src="{{asset('files/agents_pics/'.$listing->Agent->picture)}}"
           @else
            src="{{asset('files/agents_pics/default/default.png')}}"
           @endif
      >
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading" >{{$listing->Agent->first_name .' '.$listing->Agent->second_name}} </h4>
    <p style="margin: 0 0 2px;"><small>Email:</small> <a href="mailto:{{$listing->Agent->email}}">{{$listing->Agent->email}} </a></p>

    <p style="margin: 0 0 2px;" ><small>Mobile:</small> <a href="tel:{{$listing->Agent->mobile}}">{{$listing->Agent->mobile}} </a></p>
    <p><a href="" id="IDchangeAgentBtn" style="font-size: 17px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> Show Contact Info </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

as you can see text doesn't break to a new line but goes under the element, how do I fix it ? so the text will break to a new line ?

Comment: Can u please provide a JSFiddle demo of the prob? Would be much easier to help

Comment: Check your css on button or on parent DIV and remove white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure you have to specify `white-space` and `word-break` like this:

```
.media .media-body p a, .media .media-body p, .media .media-body h4 {
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

It's important to specify the selector .media .media-body p a, .media .media-body p, .media .media-body h4 tobe sure that this style have great priority over other already present styles.